# Very simple WPF program locks up (hangs) on keyboard layout change

Tags: .net, wpf

The following program locks up reproducibly whenever the user changes the keyboard layout via a key combination. It does not lock up if the keyboard layout is changed via the tray applet. It does not lock up when changing the layout to English. It does not lock up if the `Task` never executes.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox></TextBox>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Click me</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var visual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (var context = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
        }
    });
}
```

Before the button click, I can switch keyboard layouts as I please. After the click the program locks up on the first attempt to switch layouts.

**Importantly, this bug only occurs if the layouts are switched via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (and <kbd>3</kbd>, but not <kbd>1</kbd>).**

It’s way, way too late to avoid the use of `DrawingVisual` on background threads. This has become an integral, core feature of the product. Any ideas for how to work around this are very welcome.

This bug reproduces on .NET 4.0, Win7 32-bit and 64-bit.

**Bounty**: this bug affects few people in terms of percentage, but those it does affect will constantly cause the lock-up (with the corresponding data loss) every time they habitually change the keyboard layout via the shortcut. I'd like a work-around which does not change the fact that some visuals are rendered on a separate thread.

Comment: Just want to let you know that I haven't got this issue on .Net 4.0. Couldn't test it on 4.5, though.

Comment: The same for me - it works ok on .Net 4.0. I think you can report it as a bug of .Net 4.5 if you can reproduce it on clean windows installation with .Net 4.5

Comment: @Nikolay any chance you could try configuring your keyboard layouts to change when you press `Alt+Shift+2`? I’ve managed to make this happen on .NET 4 with that.

Comment: With alt+shift+2 it hangs! How did you manage to find it? This is very strange bug.

Comment: @Nikolay Thanks! Yes, it’s strange and rare... I guess that’s a good thing, since 99.9% of my users won’t see it. [My MS Connect bugreport](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/737116/wpf-application-lock-up-when-switching-keyboard-layouts).

Comment: Windows is probably telling your app that the layout changed through a windows message. Check with spy++ what kind of windows messages get sent around, and how they interleave with the keyboard messages. Maybe there is a crucial difference between the different key combinations. From there, you can try handling the messages differently from the default.

Comment: I've tried this with both .NET 4.0 on Win 7 64-bit and Win 8 64-bit with .NET 4.5 and can't repro.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Did you add a Russian keyboard layout and [enable switching to it via Alt+Shift+2](http://i.imgur.com/032bv.png)? The bug isn't triggered by just pressing Alt+Shift+2; it has to cause a layout change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Official Microsoft answer](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/737116/wpf-application-lock-up-when-switching-keyboard-layouts#tabs):

> This issue will no[t] be addressed in the next release of WPF. -WPF Team.

I’m guessing they’re all too busy with WinRT and WPF is on the back burner.

Comment: Posting WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST to a WPF program will also lock it up in exactly the same way, regardless of which keys were used to do this. Also, in Win10, the Start menu search locks up in response to Alt+Shfit+1/2.

Comment: How windows can change input language of such applications then?